# Java bubblesort 1-100

Tags: java, bubble-sort

So I have most of the code completed. I just can't figure out why the sorted list is not in order from smallest to largest. The assignment was to generate 10 random integers from 1-10. Display the unsorted list. Display sorted (smallest to largest). Display arrays contents.

```
        int [] number = new int [10];

        System.out.print("Random Numbers:");
        for (int d = 0 ; d<number.length ; d++){
            int RandomG = g.nextInt(100) + 1;
            System.out.print("\t" + RandomG);
            number[d] = RandomG ;
        }
        System.out.print("\nSorted Numbers:"+Arrays.toString(BubbleSortAsceMethod(number)));
    }

    public static int [] BubbleSortAsceMethod(int[] x) {
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < x.length -i; j++) {
                if (x[j - 1] < x[j]) {
                    temp = x[j - 1];
                    x[j - 1] = x[j];
                    x[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return x;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting each block four spaces, by making sure each line on the same block or the same block level is indented the exact same amount as the others. Yes this is a picky request, but again, we're volunteers, and you want to put in the effort to make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Also, please include your full code. You started in the middle of a method.

Comment: OK, I've tried to format your code, but it's still not understandable. It's as if you've posted enough code to frustrate us, but not enough to help us to uncover your problem. Please fix.

Comment: import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Bubblesort {
  public static void main(String [] args){
      Random g = new Random();

      int [] number = new int [10];

Comment: This is the beginning of code. I am having trouble editing the post on my laptop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the condition

current code

```
 if (x[j - 1] < x[j])
```

Fixed code

```
if (x[j - 1] > x[j])
```

However you can enhance your code by adding isSorted flag.

```
public static int[] BubbleSortAsceMethod(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
        boolean isSorted = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < x.length - i; j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
                int temp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = temp;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
        if (isSorted) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just can't figure out why the sorted list is not in order from smallest to largest.

Your problem is at `x[j - 1] < x[j]`. The condition is wrong where the `temp` variable was assigned with the small value from one-step before the current traversal value (`temp = x[j - 1]`), then it swapped with the larger value on the current traversal value which means the value before the current traversal will always have a larger value than its current traversal value. And this is why the number was sorted from the largest to lowest.

To correct it, just simply change the condition from `x[j - 1] < x[j]` into `x[j - 1] > x[j]`, where the `temp` value will be assigned with the largest value from one-step before the current traversal value and swapped its position with the lowest value on current traversal value. So that the value before the current traversal will always have a lower value than its current traversal value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] number = new int[10];
    Random g = new Random();

    System.out.print("Random Numbers:");
    for (int d = 0; d < number.length; d++) {
        int RandomG = g.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.print("\t" + RandomG);
        number[d] = RandomG;
    }

    System.out.print("\nSorted Numbers:" + Arrays.toString(BubbleSortAsceMethod(number)));
}

public static int[] BubbleSortAsceMethod(int[] x) {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < x.length - i; j++) {
            if (x[j - 1] > x[j]) {
                temp = x[j - 1];
                x[j - 1] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

**Note: Your code is not complete, so I need to complete it (for you) and perhaps it might be not the same with your actual code. Please give complete code next time when asking a question for others to understand it.**